custom label for significance (*) with its value in brackets

I need customized node near coords in such a way that the level of significance (*) with it value is shown in brackets. I tried for level of significance and its value in brackets that all went in vain. The "***" for significance with its values are in the figure shown. MWE is as follows.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{byzantine}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}
\definecolor{byzantium}{rgb}{0.44, 0.16, 0.39}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\bfseries,declare function={
            barW=10pt; 
            barShift=1.2*barW; 
        }]
        
        \begin{axis}[font={\large},
            ybar,
            bar width=25pt,
            width=30cm,
            height=15cm,
            ylabel={\bfseries Values qg/qL},
            symbolic x coords={Amber, hunch, jackbell, understep, funview, streetways, sauremilk, barracks, liphacks,},
            ymin=0.1,ymax=3.50,
            legend image code/.code={
                \draw [/tikz/.cd,bar width=20pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
                plot coordinates {(0cm,1em)};
            },
            legend style={
                at={(1.01,0.821)},
                anchor=south west,fill=none,font=\bfseries\huge,legend style={draw=none},
            },
            legend style={
                at={(0.70,0.83)},
                anchor=south west,fill=none,font=\bfseries,legend style={draw=none}
            },
            enlargelimits=0.08,
            enlarge y limits=false,
            x tick label style={font=\bfseries\Large}, ylabel style={yshift=1cm,xshift=3cm},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west,font= \Large\boldmath,rotate=90
            },
            xtick=data,             
            y tick label style={font=\boldmath}, nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={center},
            ] 
            \addplot[black, mark options={black, scale=0.75},draw=black,fill=byzantine,every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.2cm},nodes near coords, error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both, 
            y explicit relative,]table [x=x, y=y, y error=error, col sep=comma] {
                x,                  y,              error
                Amber,            0.81,             0.001
                hunch,            2.76,             0.02
                jackbell,         0.91,             0.02
                 understep,       2.01,             0.16
                funview,          1.39,             0.02
                streetways,       1.48,             0.02
                sauremilk,        2.08,             0.66
                barracks,         1.46,             0.19
                liphacks,         1.53,             0.05
            };
            \addplot[black, mark options={black, scale=0.75},draw=black,fill=byzantium!50,nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.2cm}, error bars/.cd, 
        y fixed,
        y dir=both, 
        y explicit relative,]table [x=x, y=y, y error=error, col sep=comma] {
            x,                  y,              error
            Amber,  0.18,           0.12
            hunch,        2.04,             0.22
            jackbell,         0.30,             0.45
            understep,        1.24,             0.22
            funview,          0.50,             0.22
            streetways,       0.60,             0.22
            sauremilk,        1.33,             0.15
            barracks,         0.58,             0.05
            liphacks,         0.63,             0.22
        };
            \legend{mobile (qg/qL),im-mobile (qg/qL)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}



\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{byzantine}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}
\definecolor{byzantium}{rgb}{0.44, 0.16, 0.39}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\bfseries,declare function={
            barW=10pt; % width of bars
            barShift=1.2*barW; % bar shift
        }]
        
        \begin{axis}[font={\large},
            ybar,
            bar width=25pt,
            width=30cm,
            height=15cm,
            ylabel={\bfseries\Large Values qg/qL},
            symbolic x coords={Amber, hunch, jackbell, understep, funview, streetways, sauremilk, barracks, liphacks,},
            ymin=0.1,ymax=3.50,
            legend image code/.code={
                \draw [/tikz/.cd,bar width=20pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
                plot coordinates {(0cm,1em)};
            },
            legend style={
                at={(1.01,0.821)},
                anchor=south west,fill=none,font=\bfseries\huge,legend style={draw=none},
            },
            legend style={
                at={(0.85,0.83)},
                anchor=south west,fill=none,font=\bfseries,legend style={draw=none}
            },
            enlargelimits=0.08,
            enlarge y limits=false,
            x tick label style={font=\bfseries\Large}, ylabel style={yshift=1cm,xshift=3cm},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west,font= \Large\boldmath,rotate=90
            },
            xtick=data,             
            y tick label style={font=\boldmath\Large}, nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={center},
            ] 
            \addplot[black, mark options={black, scale=0.75,},draw=black,fill=byzantine,visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*(0.1+\thisrow{error}) \as \myshift,every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.2cm},nodes near coords,point meta=explicit symbolic, error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both, 
            y explicit relative,]table [x=x, y=y, y error=error, meta=label, col sep=comma,] {
                x,                  y,              error,   label
                Amber,            0.81,             0.001,  0.81**(0.51)
                hunch,            2.76,             0.02,   2.76**(0.65)
                jackbell,         0.91,             0.02,   0.91*$\pm$0.135
                 understep,       2.01,             0.16,   2.01*$\pm$0.635
                funview,          1.39,             0.02,   1.39*$\pm$0.685
                streetways,       1.48,             0.02,   1.48*$\pm$0.785
                sauremilk,        2.08,             0.66,   2.08*$\pm$0.385
                barracks,         1.46,             0.19,   1.46*$\pm$0.085
                liphacks,         1.53,             0.05,   1.53*$\pm$0.285
            };
            \addplot[black, mark options={black, scale=0.75,},draw=black,fill=byzantium!50,visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*(0.1+\thisrow{error}) \as \myshift,every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.2cm},nodes near coords,point meta=explicit symbolic, error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both, 
            y explicit relative,]table [x=x, y=y, y error=error, meta=label, col sep=comma,] {
            x,                  y,              error,  label
            Amber,            0.18,             0.12,   0.18*(0.15)
            hunch,            2.04,             0.22,   2.04*(0.95)
            jackbell,         0.30,             0.45,   0.30*$\pm$0.135
            understep,        1.24,             0.22,   1.24*$\pm$0.635
            funview,          0.50,             0.22,   0.50*$\pm$0.685
            streetways,       0.60,             0.22,   0.60*$\pm$0.785
            sauremilk,        1.33,             0.15,   1.33*$\pm$0.385
            barracks,         0.58,             0.05,   0.58*$\pm$0.085
            liphacks,         0.63,             0.22,   0.63*$\pm$0.285
        };
            \legend{mobile (qg/qL),im-mobile (qg/qL)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

